# Does e = limit as x tends to negative infinity hold true?

Tags: limits, exponential-function

Does $$e=\displaystyle\lim_{x \to -\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\qquad\quad?$$

Comment: If you write $x = -y$, what do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to -\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$$
Put $x=-y$
$$=\displaystyle\lim_{y \to \infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{y}\right)^{-y}$$
$$=\lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{1}{y}\right)^y}=\frac{1}{e^{-1}}=e$$

Last step is from $$e^r=\displaystyle\lim_{y \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{r}{y}\right)^{y}$$

Answer (score 4):

...or, in other words, rewrite the expression as 
$$
\lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{1}{\bigg(1-\frac{1}{y}\bigg)^y}
$$

Comment: By my computation, this comes out to $e$ as well.

Comment: @AlexG.: shouldn't it?)

Answer (score -2):

if base tends to 1 after taking its separate limit and power tends to infinity
then use below formula this type of questions ...

```
       lim         (base-1)(power)
      x->infinity
    e
```

Comment: [See this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to write math on this site